# Is it possible to create Folder using Rest API ?

Tags: rest, file, api, directory

My documents has been downloaded from the server, But I want to create a folder and store this files into that folder. Is it possible.

This action should be performed before the file reaches my local system

Comment: No, It's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You can not control from withing your REST API what the client will do.